# How CLR achieve the binary level of interoperability that COM achieved? Or don't?

Tags: .net, windows, com, clr

COM is a standard of how a object is represented in memory, in binary level. With that in mind, use a COM object in any language is easy. You just need to interpret memory in a way that COM require and you`ll have the COM object in your control.

I think CLR was created with the same ideas of interoperability, but with a layer of abstraction, like, an own language (not binary). With that in mind, how CLR achieve a binary level of interoperability like COM achieved? Or don't achieved?

COM and CLR are complementary things? Or are things that replace each other, because is what MS seems to been doing.

With COM you don't depends of a Virtual Machine. With CLR you depends ever of a virtual machine?

Answer (score 4):

There is a world of difference.  COM achieves interoperability by *simplicity*.  There are incredibly few rules, just a standardized calling convention (stdcall), three methods (AddRef, Release, QueryInterface) and the notion of a jump table (aka v-table).  Everything else is built on top of that foundation, implementing COM support in a language runtime is pretty trivial and widely available.

Starkly elegant, but this does come with a price.  Particularly error handling is weak in COM, no support for exceptions.  Building libraries is troublesome, no support for implementation inheritance.  COM programming is widely considered painful and lots of effort went into hiding it as much as possible.  Most evident from WinRT, the api for Store and Windows Phone apps, powered by COM under the hood but almost completely invisible.

Managed code interoperability is achieved through IL, the Intermediary Language that all managed compilers generate, regardless of the source language.  Targeting a virtual machine spec that's well defined (Ecma 335) and very feature-rich.

Answer (score 3):

More than 15 years ago, developers working in Microsoft ecosystem had basically 3 main choices when working with COM:

- use C++
- use C++ with some help (MFC for desktop or ATL initially for servers)
- use another language. In pure Microsoft terms, it meant VB (VB4, 5, and 6). Other vendors were present (Borland, etc.).

When working with C++, developers were faced with many difficulties:

- class factories
- AddRef / Release ref counting dangers and leaks (cycles, etc.)
- threading (where COM brought the single, both, free notions)
- marshaling
- out-of-process / in-process support
- aggregation
- registration
- inexistent error handling (beyond HRESULTs)
- security
- etc.

Note that VB did a good work in some areas, and was largely adopted, but many people were dissatisfied with VB for reasons I will not mention here. Actually it also added more difficulties for C++ programmers because automation interfaces are easy to use in VB (and other automation clients such as VBScript or JScript) but difficult to use in C++ (VARIANT, BSTR, SAFEARRAY, etc.).

So Microsoft decided to create a "COM+ runtime" thing (it was part of a bigger "COM+" picture):

- To make it easier to build COM components
- To address key issues in developing and deploying COM-based apps

This is mentioned in this old 1998 article: [Object-Oriented Software Development Made Simple with COM+ Runtime Services](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/1197/complus.aspx)

Eventually, this "COM+ runtime" became something called "The .NET Framework" (and intermediary name was NGWS: Next Generation Windows Services for those like me who attended the PDC in 2001...). You can see traces of this in the name of .NET native hosting interfaces, for example [ICorRuntimeHost Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164320.aspx) where Cor stands for "COm Runtime".

So, .NET is somewhow an evolution of COM. It's based on it. It's complementary. Note that WinRT is also an evolution of COM, but quite different.

They're both descendant from COM. One way of viewing this is to consider that the .NET framework is the child of the Microsoft Developer division (Visual Studio and tools), and WinRT the child of the Microsoft Windows division (they never liked the first child mostly because of his "memory problem" - the GC).